# Tiling a tensor so I get consecutive multiples in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I would like a method that could turn [1,2,3] into [1,1,2,2,3,3].

My thought is something like

```
val = tf.constant([1.,2.,3.]) #1,2,3
tiled = tf.tile(val, 2) # [1,2,3,1,2,3]
reshaped = tf.reshape(2,3) # [[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]
transposed = tf.transpose(reshaped) # [[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]]
flattened = tf.reshape(transposed, (6,)) # [1,1,2,2,3,3]
```

I haven't tested the above, but it looks like it should work. But, is there a cleaner way to do it? Mine seems ugly.

The motivation is to make some sort of GMM, where I can get a 20-dim vector that is the concatenation of two 10-dim normal distributions, each multiplied by a different random variable. So if there's a different approach for that, I'm interested as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative without `tf.transpose`, basically add a second dimension to your tensor, `tile` by the second axis and then flatten it:

```py
t = tf.expand_dims(val, 1)
t = tf.tile(t, (1, 2))
t = tf.reshape(t, (-1,))

t.eval()
# array([ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's much better.